# Compare dates in Angular using *ngIf

Tags: angular, date

I have a scheduled date from database like this:
`scheduledDate = "2022-08-06T10:11"`

and I want to compare this scheduled date with current system time.

How can we achieve this using *ngIf in angular?

Answer (score 0):

Your `scheduledDate` property is either a string or a Date object. If it's a string you can `new Date(scheduledDate)` to make it a Date. Anyways, transform the Date to a number and compare it that way:

```
scheduledDateNumber = new Date(scheduledDate).getTime();
dateToCompare = new Date(dateToCompare).getTime();
```

Then in the html,

```
<div *ngIf="scheduledDateNumber <= dateToCompare"></div>
```